# Sliders with buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a slider plugin that allow me to insert additional buttons in a slider, not the next and prev neither numbers, I mean buttons to redirect users to a different page, etc...

I would appreciate your info!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for sliders that allow you to insert HTML content inside your slides. jQuery Cycle is a good example, look at non-image content: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Answer (score 1):

Slidedeck.com - there's a reason they have a premium version.  It's an awesome slider.